# How to float 2 divs at the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I've tried setting up my header (containing 2 divs) with

```
position: relative;
```

and both divs inside the header with

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

But I want the purple `#menu_bar` and blue `#sub_menu_bar` divs to float at the bottom of the red `#header` div.

How can I achieve that?

```css
#html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}

#menu_container {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.496);
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}

#main_container {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.526);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}

#header {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.526);
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}

#menu_bar {
    background: rgba(9, 20, 164, 0.487);
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
}

#sub_menu_bar {
    background: rgba(15, 230, 255, 0.539);
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
}

#contents {
    background: pink;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#recent_topics {
    background: green;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#stats {
    background: orange;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu_container"></div>
  <div id="main_container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="menu_bar"></div>
      <div id="sub_menu_bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents"></div>
    <div id="recent_topics"></div>
    <div id="stats"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqk2hxLw)

Comment: Do you mean "float" as in "[side by side](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-1)"? Or just want the two divs to stick at the bottom of the header?

Comment: Should've been a bit more clear about that, but I meant it as sticking to the bottom of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another div inside the header and give it a height.

Allows for less CSS, and helps semantically separate whats inside the head.
you should also use more semantic html tags such as `<header></header>` in place of `<div id="header"></div>`

You don't even need to add a height to the `<div id="header_content">` if you want it to be the height of its content.

```css
  #html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}

#menu_container {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.496);
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}

#main_container {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.526);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}

#header {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.526);
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    position: relative;
}

#header_content{
    height: 50px;
}

#menu_bar {
    background: rgba(9, 20, 164, 0.487);
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
}

#sub_menu_bar {
    background: rgba(15, 230, 255, 0.539);
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
}

#contents {
    background: pink;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#recent_topics {
    background: green;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#stats {
    background: orange;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu_container"></div>
  <div id="main_container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="header_content"></div>
      <div id="menu_bar"></div>
      <div id="sub_menu_bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents"></div>
    <div id="recent_topics"></div>
    <div id="stats"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly as well! Always nice to learn another way of doing this. Appreciate the support!

I think showdev's answer was a bit more cleaner to add, but this was good!

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't post an answer.

Comment: That make sense, the more I think about this answer, the more I realize how much this could help me in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using `position: absolute`, but if needed, do like this.

Here I added `position: relative;` to `#header` and gave the `#menu_bar`'s rule this update

```
left: 0;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 35px;
```

and `#sub_menu_bar` rule this

```
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
```

```css
#html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}

#menu_container {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.496);
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}

#main_container {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.526);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}

#header {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.526);
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu_bar {
    background: rgba(9, 20, 164, 0.487);
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
}

#sub_menu_bar {
    background: rgba(15, 230, 255, 0.539);
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#contents {
    background: pink;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#recent_topics {
    background: green;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#stats {
    background: orange;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu_container"></div>
  <div id="main_container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="menu_bar"></div>
      <div id="sub_menu_bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents"></div>
    <div id="recent_topics"></div>
    <div id="stats"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This was the exact answer I needed! Glad to see where I could've improved! Hopefully this will help many others as well. Thanks!

Comment: @VisualizeEdits Thanks, though I recommend going with _DirtyRedz_ answer, as using `position: absolute` is not a good way when not needed ... and you don't need it